# error message only appears at the 2nd click

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, error-messages

I need to show a toast with an error message on a LWC form if one of the fields has an invalid value. the validations are done and the toast appears when it's supposed to, but the message itself only appears if I click on the "submit" button a second time, never on the first. how can I correct this?

html

```
<template if:true={showErrorMessage}>
   <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_alert slds-theme_alert-texture slds-theme_error" role="alert">
       <!--error graphic-->
       <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-error slds-m-right_x-small" title="Description of icon when needed">
           <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:error" alternative-text="Error" title="Error" variant="inverse"></lightning-icon>
       </span>
       <!--error message-->
       <h2 class="alrmmsg"></h2>
   </div>
</template>
```

js (not shown here but I initialize a prop called showErrorMessage as false and this code basically just puts it to true if there's an error - and also this .catch() comes from a handleClick() function for the button you see on the screeshot)

```
.catch(error =>{
     this.showErrorMessage = true;
     if (error.body.pageErrors[0].statusCode == "FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION") {
           this.template.querySelectorAll('.alrmmsg')[0].innerHTML = error.body.pageErrors[0].message;
     } else {
            this.template.querySelectorAll('.alrmmsg')[0].innerHTML = B2B_ErrorServer;
     }
});
```

[image: error toast but no message]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please show you js code?
Have you tried adding an onclick to the div and usingd something similar to this:

```
const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: this._title,
        message: this.message,
        variant: this.variant,
    });
this.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

You can check salesforce full example here:
[Display Toast Notifications](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_toast)